# Perl Closure and References

Tags: perl

Hello I'm trying to write a simple subroutine that will compare two numbers to see if one is greater than the other, less than or equal.
So far I have the following code:

```
sub Value
{  my $num = $_[0];

   my ($last) = shift;

  my $compare = sub {    
 if ($last < $last) {print "Less than \n"; } else {print "Greater than \n";};};

 my $hashtable; 
 $hashtable->{"compare"} = $compare;
 $hashtable; }


#Execute Statement
my $num1 = Value(57.8);
my $num2 = Value(129.6);

print  "Check: ",  $num1->{"compare"}->($num2);
```

Does anyone have suggestion how I can get this to work correctly?  Thanks!

Comment: why are you comparing $last with $last? And why semicolon after else block?

Comment: I was just trying to get the "last" value, I tried comparing $num1 and $num2 but it doesn't recoginze them.  And you're right, I have one extra semicolon which i need to remove

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You messed up your argument unpacking in `Values`. You assign the first argument to `$num`, and then `shift` the first argument into `$last`, so `$num` and `$last` will always have the same value.
2. You compare `$last` with `$last`, which isn't useful.
3. You put your closure into `$hashtable->{compare}`, but execute the contents of the `check` field, which is `undef`.
4. Your closure prints data to the currently selected filehandle, but doesn't return any useful information. Printing the return value doesn't seem sensible.
5. `$num1` and `$num2` are closures, and not numbers. Passing an argument to the closure doesn't do anything, as your closure doesn't unpack any arguments.

Here is a implementation that should address your issues:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Test::More;

sub create_closure {
  my ($x) = @_;
  my $operations = {
    compare => sub { my ($y) = @_; return $x <=> $y },
    add     => sub { my ($y) = @_; return $x  +  $y },
    value   => $x,
  };
  return $operations;
}

# some tests
my $ops = create_closure(15);
ok( $ops->{compare}->(15) ==  0, "compare to self" );
ok( $ops->{compare}->(20) <   0, "compare to larger");
ok( $ops->{add}->(5)      == 20, "add");
ok( $ops->{value}         == 15, "value");

my $ops1 = create_closure(150);
ok( $ops1->{compare}->($ops->{value}) > 0, "compare to smaller value");

done_testing;
```

#### Edit

You cannot directly compare two `$ops`, but we can create a field that returns the original value.

However, you might want to use objects and operator overloading if you intend to do such things more often:

```
use strict; use warnings; use Test::More;

{
  package Ops;
  sub new {
    my ($class, $val) = @_;
    if (ref $val eq __PACKAGE__) {
      ($val, $class) = ($$val, __PACKAGE__);
    }
    bless \$val => $class;
  }
  use overload
    # overload numeric coercion
    '0+' => sub { ${ $_[0] } },
    # overload addition. Take care to dereference to avoid infinite loops.
    '+'  => sub {
      my ($self, $other) = @_;
      Ops->new($$self + $other);
    },
    # overload numeric comparision. Take care to swap the args if neccessary.
    '<=>' => sub {
      my ($self, $other, $swapped) = @_;
      (my $val, $other) = $swapped ? ($other, $$self) : ($$self, $other);
      Ops->new($val <=> $other);
    }
}

my $ops1 = Ops->new( 15);
my $ops2 = Ops->new(150);

# some tests
ok( ($ops1 <=> 15)   ==  0, "compare to self" );
ok( ($ops1 <=> 20)   <   0, "compare to larger");
ok( ($ops1  + (5))   == 20, "add");
ok(  $ops1           == 15, "value");
ok( ($ops2 <=> $ops1) >  0, "compare to smaller value");

done_testing;
```

Comment: `print chr(ord("=")+eval("$x<=>$y"))`

Comment: Is there any way I can have my $ops = create_closure(15);
 and my $ops1 = create_closure(150);
 and compare those numbers? so it would be like $ops->{compare}->$ops1

Comment: @KevenDiuliy You can include a field that gives back the original value. I also included an example of operator overloading, which might be a bit advanced, but is quite powerful.

Answer (score 1):

do it like this:

```
 our $last;

 sub compare
 {
    my ($x, $y) = @_;
    if( $x > $y )
    {
       print("$x is greater than $y\n");
    }
    elsif( $x == $y )
    {
       print("$x is equal to $y\n");
    }
    else
    {
       print("$x is less than $y\n");
    }

    $last = ($x, $y);
 };
 my $lastValues = compare(3, 4); # pass numbers which you want to compare instead of 3 and 4

 print("last compared value = $lastValues");
```

Comment: Thank you so much but when i execute, i need to use the following format: print "Check: ", $num1->{"check"}->($num2); this way it checks the hashtable first

Comment: what this hashtable is doing exactly?In my code, I just stored the last compared values in a global variable.

Comment: In my full code I have hashtable that has different values such as add, divide, mulitply..I'm pretty much building a calculator, but i can't figure out how the execution statement in that particular format can pass in the parameters correctly

Comment: okay! you should read about infix, prefix and postfix notations, that'll help you in this task.

Comment: @Stillakid ah, and where normal closures?